# Recognize cell contents in VBA

Tags: excel

im  trying to create a  code that can help me to paste my formulas in a range.

the range is always changing as i have to include information on a daily basis at the en of my list

the existing code almost gets the job done but6 instead of recognizing the value on cell a1 (a count of the amount of records to calculate) it pastes the information on range e1:k1

```
Sub Run_Formulas()
'
' Run_Formulas Macro
'
 Dim As Variant

 x1 As Variant

 x1 = Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A1")

'
Range("E4:K4").Select
    Selection.Copy
Range("E8" & ":" & "K" & "a1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, 
SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

how can i get the macro to recognize the contents of cell a1 and to use it for my final range/

Comment: I'm puzzled, what is happening here >>Range("E8" & ":" & "K" & "a1").Select<< ?  Is the resulting range  E8:Ka1  ?  doesn't seem right.

Comment: let say i have 15 records,

the content of cell A1 is a count a, so therefore it will result in a number.

what i intend is to generate a dinamic range so every time i press my button the macro willo run the formulas for the total amount of records

Comment: Change that to >>Range("E8" & ":" & "K" & Trim(Str(sheets("Raw Data").Cells(1,"A")))).Select<<  which will get the CONTENTS of A1 translated into a string and trimmed of its leading space.

Comment: *Solution*

Sub Run_Formulas()
'
' Run_Formulas Macro
'
Sheets("Raw Data").Select

 

Dim X1 As Variant

Dim X2 As Variant

 

X1 = Range("a1")

X2 = X1 + 11

 

Range("e4:k4").Select

Selection.Copy

 

Range("e8" & ":" & "k" & X2).Select

ActiveSheet.Paste

 

    Selection.Copy

       Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

 

End Sub